# Why "%d" is not equivalent to " %d" as a format string in scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I'm reading a book and solving some problems. The question is

> For each of the following pairs of `scanf` format strings, indicate
>   whether or not the two strings are equivalent. If they're not, show
>   how they can be distinguished.
>
> (a) `"%d"` veruss `" %d"`
>
> (b) `"%d-%d-%d"` versus `"%d -%d -%d"`
>
> (c) `"%f"` versus `"%f "`
>
> (d) `"%f,%f"` versus `"%f, %f"`

My solution is (a) they are equivalent since `scanf` discards the white space. For (b) they are not equivalent since `scanf` matches `-` with white space . For (c), they are not equivalent since `scanf` will put back the white space in the buffer. For (d), they are equivalent since `scanf` discards white space. According to the Chegg solutions, all preceding questions are not equivalent. Am I wrong? In this post, I would like to make sure that my answers are correct in comparison with Chegg solutions. I've already read the book and I have decent knowledge about `scanf`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between different scanf formats](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126126/difference-between-different-scanf-formats)

Comment: @rsp, not exactly. I've already provided answers. Also, I'm comparing my solutions to Chegg solutions. Moreover, it is not homework question.

Comment: @CroCo any reason to revert the list formatting to a chunk of tough-to-read text?

Comment: @CroCo "According to the Chegg solutions" --> According to the book by Cheng, what is the difference between `"%d"` versus `" %d"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"%d"` and `" %d"` are the same per OP's reasoning.

They are certainly the same with expected numeric input like `"123"` and `" 456"`.  A remaining consideration would be where is the `FILE` pointer on failure as with `"abc"` versus `" xyz"`?  `"%d"` by itself, *first* consumes leading white-space. So no difference.

> ... A conversion specification is executed in the following steps: C11dr  §7.21.6.2 7
>
> Input white-space characters ... are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier. §7.21.6.2 8

*then* the conversion of text to numeric input (for `"%d"`) happens.

Below code demonstrates equivalence.

```
void next_testi(const char *s, const char *fmt, const char *pad) {
  rewind(stdin);
  int i = 0;
  int count = scanf(fmt, &i);
  int next = fgetc(stdin);
  printf("format:\"%s\",%s count:%2d, i:%2d, next:%2d, text:\"%s\"\n", //
      fmt, pad, count, i, next, s);
}

void next_test(const char *s) {
  FILE *fout = fopen("test.txt", "w");
  fputs(s, fout);
  fclose(fout);

  freopen("test.txt", "r", stdin);
  next_testi(s, "%d", " ");
  next_testi(s, " %d", "");
  puts("");
}

int main() {
  next_test("3");
  next_test(" 4");
  next_test("");
  next_test(" ");
  next_test("+");
  next_test(" -");
  next_test("X");
  next_test(" Y");
}
```

Output

```
format:"%d",  count: 1, i: 3, next:-1, text:"3"  // scanf() return value 1:success
format:" %d", count: 1, i: 3, next:-1, text:"3"

format:"%d",  count: 1, i: 4, next:-1, text:" 4"
format:" %d", count: 1, i: 4, next:-1, text:" 4"

format:"%d",  count:-1, i: 0, next:-1, text:""  // scanf() return value EOF, next is EOF
format:" %d", count:-1, i: 0, next:-1, text:""

format:"%d",  count:-1, i: 0, next:-1, text:" "
format:" %d", count:-1, i: 0, next:-1, text:" "

format:"%d",  count: 0, i: 0, next:43, text:"+" // scanf() return value 0
format:" %d", count: 0, i: 0, next:43, text:"+"

format:"%d",  count: 0, i: 0, next:45, text:" -"
format:" %d", count: 0, i: 0, next:45, text:" -"

format:"%d",  count: 0, i: 0, next:88, text:"X"
format:" %d", count: 0, i: 0, next:88, text:"X"

format:"%d",  count: 0, i: 0, next:89, text:" Y"
format:" %d", count: 0, i: 0, next:89, text:" Y"
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, with a little modification to option (c) reasoning.

> *"scanf will put back the white space in the buffer."*

I don't really understand your version, but actually, `scanf()` literally matches the input with the supplied format string, and alongside `%f` conversion specifier, a single non-leading whitespace needs to be *matched* with any number of whitespaces, until a non-whitespace is read.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.2

> A directive composed of white-space character(s) is executed by reading input up to the
>   first non-white-space character (which remains unread), or until no more characters can
>   be read. The directive never fails.

Comment: In (c), `scanf` will wait until the user enters a non-white-space character, as I understood from the book, so my claim for the options being not equivalent is correct.

Comment: `"%d-%d-%d"` and `"%d -%d -%d"` are not the same. An input string of `"1- 2      -3"`  will not be parsed by the former, but will be parsed by the latter

Comment: @nos Ahh, I seem to have miss that, should be right.